# NetLogo - turtle to go to the closest concentration of turtles

Tags: netlogo

I would like a turtle to go to the closest patches with most turtles if  a  threshold of a given variable is met for 5 ticks.

My code is:

```
to move
  let count-tick 5
  if var >= 9.5 [
    set count-tick count-tick - 1
    if count-tick = 0 [
      ask turtle [
        let nearest-group min-one-of (patches with [sum turtles >= 3] in-radius 3 ) [ distance myself ]
        move-to nearest-group ;; go to the biggest crowd near you
        ask turtle [ ;; once there do the following
          set shape "star"
          set color red
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]  
end
```

The issue I have is that a) I am unsure how to say `the patch with >= 3 turtles closest to you at the given range of 3` (attempted code above) and b) how to say `once there, change your shape`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised to keep a permanent variable to track whether the variable is high enough 5 times in a row.

```
turtles-own
[ count-tick
]

; wherever you create the turtles, you need to `set count-tick 5`

to move
  ifelse var >= 9.5
  [ set count-tick count-tick - 1 ]
  [ set count-tick 5 ]
  if count-tick = 0
  [ let nearest-group min-one-of (patches with [count turtles >= 3] in-radius 3 ) [ distance myself ]
    move-to nearest-group ;; go to the biggest crowd near you
    set shape "star"
    set color red
  ]
end
```

First, you are already within an `ask turtles` code block from the procedure calling this move procedure. So you don't need the additional `ask turtles`. Look up `ask` in the NetLogo Dictionary, it iterates through the turtles, running all the code for each turtle in turn.

Second, you need `count turtles` rather than `sum turtles` as `sum` is to add up values.

Note that there is no error checking in this, you may have problems if there are no patches within radius of 3 that have at least 3 turtles.

Comment: Hi JenB, you answer seem to look good, unfortunately the above code does not function, it does simple nothing as it turns out. Even if I have 1000 turtles in the simulation (in order to avoid not having at least 3 turtles within a radius of 3), no turtle has change its shape ever. How I can fix the above code?

Comment: It seems to have to do with `count-tick`. If the value is 1, it does function, once it is 2 or higher, it does not seem to have any effect. Did I do something wrong there?

Comment: yes, the problem is that each tick, the counter resets to value 5 (with the first line). If you want the turtle to remember, then you need it as a permanent attribute rather than created each tick. I will revise.

Comment: JenB, you wrote `Note that there is no error checking in this, you may have problems if there are no patches within radius of 3 that have at least 3 turtles.` Interestingly, it just crashes (with a nobody error) if there is just two turtles. May I add an `if (not) any?` before the part `patches with`?

Comment: Yes, that is what you should do in your code. But it's not relevant to the answer because you were asking how to do the searching.